# Server connection failed when connecting sql-azure from tsql/freetds

Tags: azure-sql-database, freetds

I am working on Mac OSX 10.9.4 and I have installed freetds via brew.

When I try "TDSVER=7.2 tsql -H XXX.database.windows.net -p 1433", I receive the message "error 20002 (severity 9): Adaptive Server connection failed. There was a problem connecting to the server"

Result of "tsql -C" :
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.91/etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: no
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 7.1
                              iODBC: yes
                           unixodbc: no
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: no

I have tried TDSVER 7.1 / 7.2, it doesn't help.

I am sure that the database is up and running and that my IP is trusted on the server as I can telnet the server on port 1433.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following:

"TDSVER=7.1 tsql -H XXX.database.windows.net -p 1433 -U <'userName'> -P <'password'>"